# Angular Reactive Form shows errors after reload / submit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a Angular Form in my component that allows a user to add an email to a list. It is rather simple and after submitting the view reloads the list of email subscribers using an API call and then the user can add another email... this is my HTML in my template

```
<form [formGroup]="addEmailToListForm" (ngSubmit)="addEmailToList()"  autofill="off" novalidate>
    <div class="email-subscriber-list__control">
      <div class="email-subscriber-list__control__input">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input formControlName="email" matInput
                 placeholder="Subscriber"
                 autocomplete="off">
        </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!addEmailToListForm.valid">
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Now in my component code file I have the following methods to create the form and submit the form, the create is only ran when `ngOnInit()`

```
createAddEmailToListForm(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email],
        this.subscriberEmailUniqueValidator.validate.bind(this)
      )
    });
  }

  addEmailToList(): void {
    const data = {
      type: this.subscriptionType,
      subscriber: this.addEmailToListForm.controls['email'].value,
      tags: {
        company: this.selectedCompany
      }
    };

    const companyId = this.selectedCompany ? this.selectedCompany.id : null;

    this.apiService.createEmailSubscription(data, companyId).subscribe((resp: any) => {
        if (resp.message === 'Successfully created') {
         // reset the list and form item
          this.apiService
            .getEmailSubscriptions(this.subscriptionType, companyId).subscribe((emails) => {
            this.subscriptionList = emails;
          });
          this.addEmailToListForm.reset();
          this.addEmailToListForm.setErrors(null);
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        // do something...
      });
  }
```

This all great but I have noticed that when the page loads the `<mat-form-field>` shows no error state, which is great. After submitting the form the `<mat-form-field>` shows an error state (the text colour and bottom border is red) even though I reset the form using `reset()`  and `.setErrors(null);` I have tried to set the form control's errors to null, but this removes the validators (so a empty value can be submitted) or if I try to `markAsPristine` or `markAsUntouched`. Any ideas how I can get this problem resolved. Some visuals are below to help my question

**Before Submit**
[image]
**After Submit**
[image]

Comment: how about:  this.addEmailToListForm.reset({email: ''})

Comment: Still get the same problem - thanks anyway

Comment: try: this.addEmailToListForm?.markAsUntouched({onlySelf: true});    after   this.addEmailToListForm.setErrors(null);